# Which ".h" file to use for a jailbreak tweak

Tags: ios, jailbreak

So I am pretty new to *Objective C* and just trying to make a tweak! The code works well on *Xcode*, but I want to just change it so that it works as a *jailbreak tweak*. Essentially when you are on your home *screen/ springboard*, you just tap and hold on the screen for a second, and gives you a `UIAlertView` with 3 buttons. I just want to know how I can translate this on the *springboard*! Which header file should I be using!

Here is my code that I use on *Xcode*:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

self.lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGestures:)];
self.lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
self.lpgr.allowableMovement = 100.0f;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.lpgr];
}

- (void)handleLongPressGestures:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
  {
     if ([sender isEqual:self.lpgr]) 
   {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
          UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Gestures" message:@"Long Gesture Detected" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Message", @"Facetime", @"Phone", nil];
        [alertView show];

    }
}
}


  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    NSLog(@"Message");
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:+1234567890"]];


}

if (buttonIndex == 2)
{
    NSLog(@"Facetime");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://tel-number"]];


}
if (buttonIndex == 3)
{
    NSLog(@"Phone");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:%@"]];

}

   }
```

Comment: code never *work on Xcode* — it is an IDE, it does not execute any code.

Comment: Likely he means it works in the simulator?

Comment: well I just want to know which method and class should I use for a tweak, where I just want to long press tap on springboard and it should give me a UIAlert! I am using UIView and -(id)_gesturerecognizers as the method!